# Make navigation clickable in fullpage script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple project based on one variation of fullpage script. Everything works perfect except for one annoying thing - I can't understand how to make my right navigation bullets clickable (to an appropriate section). My js knowledge is not too good at the moment so I'd really appreciate any help, guys. Thanks!

```js
$.fullPage = function(option) {
  var defaultOpt = {
      box: "#fullPageBox", // 滚屏页父元素
      page: ".fullPage", // 滚屏页面
      index: true, // 是否显示索引
      duration: 1000, // 动画时间
      direction: "vertical", // 滚屏方向 horizontal or vertical
      loop: true // 是否循环
    },
    This = this,
    index = 0,
    over = true;
  this.option = $.extend({}, defaultOpt, option || {});
  this.box = $(this.option.box);
  this.pages = $(this.option.page);
  this.duration = this.option.duration;

  // 绑定鼠标滚轮事件
  $(document).on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(ev) {
    var dir = ev.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -ev.originalEvent.detail;
    if (over === false) return;
    dir < 0 ? nextPage() : prevPage();
  });

  if (this.option.index) {
    initPagination();
  };

  function initPagination() {
    var oUl = $("<ul id='fullPageIndex'></ul>"),
      liStr = "";
    for (var i = 0, len = This.pages.length; i < len; i++) {
      liStr += "<li></li>";
    };
    $(document.body).append(oUl.append($(liStr)));
    $("#fullPageIndex li").eq(index).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
  };

  function nextPage() {
    if (index < This.pages.length - 1) {
      index++;
    } else {
      index = 0;
    }
    scrollPage(index, This.pages.eq(index).position());
  };

  function prevPage() {
    if (index === 0) {
      index = This.pages.length - 1;
    } else {
      index--;
    }
    scrollPage(index, This.pages.eq(index).position());
  };

  function scrollPage(index, position) {
    over = false;
    var cssStr = This.option.direction === "vertical" ? {
      top: -position.top
    } : {
      left: -position.left
    };
    This.box.animate(cssStr, This.duration, function() {
      over = true;
    })
    $("#fullPageIndex li").eq(index).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
  };

}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pageBox {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500%;
  min-width: 1200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.main .fullPage {
  height: 25%;
}

.bg1 {
  background-color: #27AE60;
}

.bg2 {
  background-color: #3498DB;
}

.bg3 {
  background-color: #C0392B;
}

.bg4 {
  background-color: #4FC2E5;
}

.bg5 {
  background-color: #8E44AD;
}

#fullPageIndex {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#fullPageIndex li {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#fullPageIndex li.active {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <div class="pageBox">
    <div class="main" id="fullPageBox">
      <div class="fullPage bg1">jQuery fullPage.js</div>
      <div class="fullPage bg2">Section 2</div>
      <div class="fullPage bg3">Section 3</div>
      <div class="fullPage bg4">Section 4</div>
      <div class="fullPage bg5">Section 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $.fullPage();
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an id attribute to you divs and add  an anchor to the list elements that navigate to the desired sections. As follows:

```
<body>
  <div class="pageBox">
    <div class="main" id="fullPageBox">
      <div id="section1" class="fullPage bg1">jQuery fullPage.js</div>
      <div id="section2" class="fullPage bg2">Section 2</div>
      <div id="section3" class="fullPage bg3">Section 3</div>
      <div id="section4" class="fullPage bg4">Section 4</div>
      <div id="section5" class="fullPage bg5">Section 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $.fullPage();
  </script>

</body>
```

Update your js where you render the list items to look like this:

```
function initPagination() {
  var oUl = $("<ul id='fullPageIndex'></ul>"),
    liStr = "";
  for (var i = 0, len = This.pages.length; i <= len; i++) {
    var sectionNum = i + 1;
    liStr += '<li><a href="#section' + sectionNum + '"></a></li>';
  };
  $(document.body).append(oUl.append($(liStr)));
  $("#fullPageIndex li").eq(index).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
};
```

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Linking_to_another_section_on_the_same_page)

EDIT:

Since you asked for a smooth scroll as well you could add this to your JS:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
           if (target.length) {
             $('html,body').animate({
                 scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Source for the snippet can be found on [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) page.

Comment: Thanks! Works fine, but how can I add a smooth animation for scrolling by the click?

Comment: Works great! Thanks so much, mate!

Answer (score 1):

there is some mistake in your script.

First, remove below code from your HTML file:

```
<script>
  fullPage();
</script>
```

Second is, you've created wrong function (method) define. I'am replace `$.fullpage = function(option) {` with `var fullpage = function(options) {`

and for the last is: since we have removed your `fullpage()` initiator, so we need to call this method again. for example at end line of your JS file,

---

**P.S:**

In Javascript you can create `function` in several ways. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions for more detail.

See fixed code below:

```js
var fullPage = function(option) {
  var defaultOpt = {
      box: "#fullPageBox", // 滚屏页父元素
      page: ".fullPage", // 滚屏页面
      index: true, // 是否显示索引
      duration: 1000, // 动画时间
      direction: "vertical", // 滚屏方向 horizontal or vertical
      loop: true // 是否循环
    },
    This = this,
    index = 0,
    over = true;
  this.option = $.extend({}, defaultOpt, option || {});
  this.box = $(this.option.box);
  this.pages = $(this.option.page);
  this.duration = this.option.duration;

  // 绑定鼠标滚轮事件
  $(document).on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(ev) {
    var dir = ev.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -ev.originalEvent.detail;
    if (over === false) return;
    dir < 0 ? nextPage() : prevPage();
  });

  if (this.option.index) {
    initPagination();
  };

  function initPagination() {
    var oUl = $("<ul id='fullPageIndex'></ul>"),
      liStr = "";
    for (var i = 0, len = This.pages.length; i < len; i++) {
      liStr += "<li></li>";
    };
    $(document.body).append(oUl.append($(liStr)));
    $("#fullPageIndex li").eq(index).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
  };

  function nextPage() {
    if (index < This.pages.length - 1) {
      index++;
    } else {
      index = 0;
    }
    scrollPage(index, This.pages.eq(index).position());
  };

  function prevPage() {
    if (index === 0) {
      index = This.pages.length - 1;
    } else {
      index--;
    }
    scrollPage(index, This.pages.eq(index).position());
  };

  function scrollPage(index, position) {
    over = false;
    var cssStr = This.option.direction === "vertical" ? {
      top: -position.top
    } : {
      left: -position.left
    };
    This.box.animate(cssStr, This.duration, function() {
      over = true;
    })
    $("#fullPageIndex li").eq(index).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
  };

}

fullPage();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pageBox {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500%;
  min-width: 1200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.main .fullPage {
  height: 25%;
}

.bg1 {
  background-color: #27AE60;
}

.bg2 {
  background-color: #3498DB;
}

.bg3 {
  background-color: #C0392B;
}

.bg4 {
  background-color: #4FC2E5;
}

.bg5 {
  background-color: #8E44AD;
}

#fullPageIndex {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#fullPageIndex li {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#fullPageIndex li.active {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <div class="pageBox">
    <div class="main" id="fullPageBox">
      <div class="fullPage bg1">jQuery fullPage.js</div>
      <div class="fullPage bg2">Section 2</div>
      <div class="fullPage bg3">Section 3</div>
      <div class="fullPage bg4">Section 4</div>
      <div class="fullPage bg5">Section 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The original question was about making the navigation bullets clickable and making the bullets scroll to the appropriate sections. This answer does not address this.